# How to check if directory exist on remote windows machine before sftp file?

Tags: ssh, sftp, remote-access, remote-server, remote-desktop

want to transfer a file from Unix machine to remote window machine.
But before that need to check "/MONTH/JAN/" folder exists on the remote machine if the folder doesn't exist then create a folder.

```
DIR=/MONTH/JAN/

ssh <user>@<server> "test -d $DIR"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
sftp <user>@<server> << EOF
mkdir $DIR
bye
EOF
else
   echo 'Directory '${DIR}' exists'
fi
```

But here ssh is not working.
Facing below error

```
shell request failed on channel 0
```

Any other way to test folder's existence?